# How to execute .load() on http post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

In my application, I have a piece of code that "catches" all the clicks on an anchor, and loads it into my page:

```
$("a").live("click", function () {
    var src = $(this).attr("href");
    if ($(this).attr("target") === "_blank")
        return true;
    $("#myPage").load(src + " #myPage");
    return false;
});
```

Now this works on all anchor tags. How can I make all my POST requests (sending forms data) behave like that?

Edit: As Kevin said, I tried using .post, but it doesn't work for me, what did I do wrong? Here's the code:

```
$("form").post("submit", function () {
    var src = $(this).attr("action");
    $("#myPage").load(src + " #myPage");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: on post data what do you want to do

Comment: @KevinB: Could you be more specific?

Comment: @ArunPJohny: I want my post data to be sent and given back to me without page refreshing.

Comment: so, yo have forms in your page which are getting submitted

Comment: @ojek You want to catch Form Submit to be more precise. POST requests could mean ajax requests.

Comment: In older versions of jQuery (which you are most likely using since you are using `live()` which doesn't exist in the most recent version and has been depreciated for a LONG time.), Delegating to the form submit event didn't work in all browsers. If that's the case in your version, you're pretty much out of luck unless you want to implement it youself. You could delegate to the click of the form's submit button though.

Comment: Well, I am using jQuery version 1.9 and as far as I know, it isn't that old...

Comment: @ojek in that case, just do the same thing you are doing for `a` tags with `form` tags and the submit event instead. don't forget to use .post rather than load

Comment: You should also stop using .live and instead use .on if you are using jQuery 1.9, that way you can eventually move away from the migrate plugin.

Comment: @KevinB: But as far as I know, .on doesn't work on dynamically created elements, am I right?

Comment: @ojek It does, if you use it correctly. For example, your anchor tag event should be written as `$(document).on("click","a",function(){...` Delegated events are typically bound to an ancestor element. Events bubble up to it, then the handler tests whether the event's target matches the target selector, in this case anchor tags.

Comment: @KevinB: .post doesn't want to work for me, could you look at my code (I updated my post)?

Comment: @KevinB: You were right, .on works just fine, thank you. But this .post still doesn't want to.

Comment: @Ojek What i meant by `.post` was replace your `.load` with `.post`, or `.ajax` with `type: 'POST'`. *Arun P Johny* covered it pretty well below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the form submit event to handle form POST case

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: $this.attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: $this.serialize()
    }).done(function(responseText){
        $("#myPage").html(responseText)
    });

    return false;
})
```

Since you are using jquery 1.9, you may have to rewrite the `a` handler as

```
$(document).on("click", 'a', function () {
    var src = $(this).attr("href");
    if ($(this).attr("target") === "_blank")
        return true;
    $("#myPage").load(src + " #myPage");
    return false;
});
```

Comment: which one, the form submit one?

Comment: @ojek That would suggest an error is happening with `$.ajax`. To view it, use this variation of the above code: http://pastebin.com/pELvSsiv and then check the console.

Comment: @KevinB there was a spelling mistake in the `serialize` method call

Comment: @ArunPJohny My point was using e.preventDefault prevents the submit before any errors can happen, thus allowing you to see what the errors are rather than the code never reaching `return false`

Comment: @ArunPJohny: You edited your code three times, and the one edit before the last one was working, this one isn't. Something is wierd...

Comment: @KevinB: Your code makes my page to stop for a few seconds. O.o

Comment: Also, on this code above, the page refreshes for a few times :D

Comment: what do you mean by few times

Comment: Well, maybe it's my fault, I was using this on a newly written form that had a wrong action specified, fixed action and everything works. Thank you for helping me guys. :)